# Focusout automatically after focusin

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote some simple jQuery code for a mobile website. If I touch the delete button it clears the input and focuses in an input area. However it automatically focus out after `focus()`

```js
$(document).on('focusin', '#testInput', function() {
  console.log('in')
});

$(document).on('focusout', '#testInput', function() {
  console.log('out')
});

$(document).on('touchstart', '#deleteButton', function() {
  console.log('touchs')
  $('#testInput').val('').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="title">
    <span>MOBILE TEST</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <input type='text' id="testInput" name="testInput" class="input_text">
    <button id="deleteButton" type="button" class="delete_button">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why You don't use the `tap` event? This is *the standard* for user
   interaction.

   You need to remember that it is the *user interaction* which is
   stealing the focus from the active element. There isn't any magic
   "event trigger" behind that. At most, the sequence order of the many
   `touchstart`, `mousedown`. `click`, `tap`, and so on... is
   browser-dependent and need some quirks to work correctly
   cross-browser. You should use the `tap` event also because, just for
   instance, the user should be able to leave the finger from the
   cancel button and nothing should happen.
2. Besides this, if You absolutely stick with `touchstart` and Your
   button is just like a kind of graphical input and don't need a click
   or whatsoever event, try this and see that it will work:

   ```
   $('#deleteButton').on('touchstart', function() {
     $('#testInput').val('').focus();
     return false;
   });
   ```
3. But in Your example You are using `event delegation`. Read this:
   [What is DOM Event
   delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

   So, if You need `event delegation`. there is also the need to stop
   the event bubbling:

   ```
   $(document).on('touchstart', '#deleteButton', function(e) {
     $('#testInput').val('').focus();
     return false;
   });
   $(document).on('touchend', '#deleteButton', function(e) {
     return false;
   });
   ```

---

Eventually, here is a great explanation about `return false` inside the jQuery event handlers:

> [event.preventDefault() vs. return
>   false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/4845566)